# How to use if-let with subscript in Swift?

Tags: swift

Got this error:

> Referencing subscript 'subscript(_:)' on 'Optional' requires the types '[String : Api]' and 'any Primitive' be equivalent

```swift
if let key = key,
    let team = sharedState.team(),
    let api = team.apis[key], // <-------
```

and the model, what is wrong?

```swift
struct Api: Codable {
    var url: String
    var method: String
}

struct Team: Codable {
    var apis: [String: Api]?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary subscript does return an optional, and this allows you to use it in `if let`. However, in your case, the *dictionary itself* is optional.

You need to unwrap the optional that is wrapping the dictionary too. You can do this with optional chaining by adding a `?` before `[`:

```
if let key = key,
    let team = sharedState.team(),
    let api = team.apis?[key] {

}
```

Or have an extra `let` that unwraps the dictionary:

```
if let key = key,
    let team = sharedState.team(),
    let apis = team.apis,
    let api = apis[key] {

}
```

This allows you to also use the non-optional dictionary inside the if block.